# 3d parent child relationship libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I have 2 arms attached to each other like **parent-child** in 3d (`.g3dj file`). My requirement is that when parent arm rotates/move then child arm should also rotate/move while being connected to parent at one point. I am able to achieve that.

Child arm can also rotate independently while being connected to its parent at give point and parent itself should not move in this case. I am stuck in below case :

1. When parent moves/rotates then child also moves/rotates. At
   certain angle of parent movement/rotation, if the child rotated 360 
   degree then no distortion is seen.
2. If child rotates/moves then its angle and orientation changes. The    child position gets distorted from parent when parent is further    rotated/moved in this case.

I think a **bone hierarchy** is required. Please suggest the method/link so that in all cases parent-child position (at the point of contact) never distort irrespective of their movement/rotation. Thanks.

Below is the code that I have tried so far:

```
private void createBaseArm1(){
    // Now load the model by name from asset folder
    baseArm1 = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle(armPathWithName + ".g3dj", Files.FileType.Internal));

    //getting boundingBox for model to retrieve its co-ordinates
    baseArm1.calculateBoundingBox(baseBoundingBox);

    baseArm1PositionX = 0f;
    baseArm1PositionY = -3.0f;
    baseArm1PositionZ = 1.0f;

    baseArm1PositionVector = new Vector3(baseArm1PositionX, baseArm1PositionY, baseArm1PositionZ);

    baseArm1Instance = new ModelInstance(baseArm1, baseArm1PositionVector);
    baseArm1Instance.transform.set(baseArm1PositionVector, baseArm1Rotation);

    baseArm1TopPositionY = baseArm1PositionY + baseBoundingBox.getHeight();

}

private void createArm2(){
    arm2Vector = new Vector3(baseArm1PositionX,baseArm1TopPositionY ,baseArm1PositionZ);
    armModel2 = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("arm2.g3dj", Files.FileType.Internal));
    arm2Instance = new ModelInstance(armModel2, arm2Vector);
    arm2Instance.transform.set(arm2Vector, arm2Rotation);
}

public void moveBaseArm1() {

    baseArm1Instance.transform.translate(0, 0, 0).rotate(0, 0, 1, 10).translate(0, 0, 0);
    arm2Instance.transform
            .translate(-0, -baseBoundingBox.getHeight(), -baseBoundingBox.getDepth())
            .rotate(0, 0, 1, 10)
            .translate(0, baseBoundingBox.getHeight(), baseBoundingBox.getDepth());


}

public void moveArm2() {
    arm2Instance.transform.translate(0,0,0).rotate(0, 0, 1, 10).translate(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is both `.g3dj files` -> [Parent-Child-Relationship Git Repository](https://github.com/tauqir295/Parent-Child-Relationship)

Comment: Why are you using two separate models instead of just one? Which modeling application are you using to create the models? How is the node structure in each of these models? Perhaps consider including the contents of the g3dj file.

Comment: @Xoppa, I have very little knowledge about how to use one model instead of two. I have gone through libgdx tutorial for using one model but could not understand it properly. So I have used two models as per my analysis. Also I am using `blender.exe` to export `.g3dj` file. Can you please specify what is `node structure`. I have given url for `g3dj` files.

Comment: A node structure allows you to create a parent child relationship within the model. You can have as many nodes within a single model as you like and every node can be transformed independently, causing all its child nodes to be transformed as well. See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Models. Also make sure to read my 3D tutorials at: http://blog.xoppa.com, they give you an introduction in nodes as well and how they work in libgdx. I don't know blender, but it's a basic modelling concept, so it shouldn't be hard to find how to use it in blender.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this.

Comment: Xoppa is a legend. You should know that.